# Javascript for HTTPS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, https

I've been going through google, bing, etc etc trying to find out how I can get my scripts to run correctly, but google chrome says that it's attempting to load scripts from unauthenticated sources, and I'm not 100% sure what it means by that.

Here's my login page that runs fine on localhost, but chrome doesn't like running the script.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('#login').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'calls.php',
            data: $('#login').serialize(),
            success: function (data, response) {
            if(data==1)
            {    window.location.href = "/account.php";
                return false;}
            else{ $( ".result" ).html( data );}
            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>
<div style="background-image:url('img/doxramos.png'); background-size:100% 100%; width:455px; height:188px;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"></div>
  <form method="post" class="login" id="login" action="calls.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="process" id="process" value="login">
      <label for="login">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="name@example.com">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    </p>

    <p class="login-submit">
      <button type="submit" class="login-button" id="submit">Login</button>
    </p>

    <p class="forgot-password"><a href="index.html">Forgot your password?</a></p>
  </form>
<div class = "result" style="text-align:center; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"></div>
```

Comment: Any change it could be an HTTPS issue? Try loading everything via https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you're running the current file/page with SSL, but you're getting resources from non-https URL's.

Just change the URL

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: I never thought that the solution would be so simple. I'll accept the answer in 9 minutes when it lets me. Would it be better to host everything locally? I've heard that can impact performance, but I'm not 100% sure on it.

Comment: That depends, but there's nothing wrong with getting resources like jQuery from other sources, but every resource you include has to be included from an HTTPS url, otherwise it's not secure, and it defeats the purpose of running SSL.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. I never thought about it, but it's logical and I kind of deserve the dunce hat at this point.